# Iterate through the list and grouping based on dates

Tags: java

I am trying to achieve, where I am looking for ways to group the list based on the dates. I have a lost of attribute as below:

```
List<Attribute> attributes
```

where 
    Attribute.java is as below

```
public class Attribute
{
    Integer getValue();
    List<String> getString();
    Date getDate();
}
```

I am looking for a way such that , while iterating through the list of Attribute , I could create a List of elements (current date) and map of elements based on the dates (in the past) having the same IntegerValue.

My codes goes as below:

```
List<Attribute> currentElement = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
Map<Integer, List<Attribute>> historicalElement = new HashMap<Integer, List<Attribute>>();

//iterating the entire list
for(final Attribute attribute : attributes) 
{
  if(attribute.getDate() == currentDate)
  {
      currentElement.add(attribute);
  }
  if(attribute.getDate() < currentDate)
  {
      historicalElement.put(attribute.getValue(), attribute)     
  }
}
```

The statement

```
historicalElement.put(attribute.getValue(), attribute)
```

wont work beacuse

```
The method put(Integer, List<Attribute>) in the type Map<Integer,List<Attribute>> is not applicable for the arguments (Integer,   Attribute).
```

Is there any way that we can achieve that map , rather than typing casting to List.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

Casting to list won't help at all. You'll only get a `ClassCastException`. Simplest way might be this:

```
if(attribute.getDate() < currentDate)
{
    List<Attribute> list = historicalElement.get(attribute.getValue());
    if(list == null){
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        historicalElement.put(attribute.getValue() , list);
    }

    list.add(attribute);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

edit: Paul's answer is better here.

Looks like a job for [guava multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) where you can do:

```
Map<Integer, List<Attribute>> historicalElement = Multimaps.newListMultimap();
for(final Attribute attribute : attributes) {
    historicalElement.put(attribute.getValue(), attribute)
}
```

should do it.

Well, except that you want to group by the date as well? That's slightly trickier.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to fix your date comparison. You don't compare dates using `==` operator.

Now while adding a new entry in map, you've to first check the existing key. If not there then create a new `ArrayList` with new value:

```
if(attribute.getDate().compareTo(currentDate) < 0) {
    if (historicalElement.containsKey(attribute.getValue())) {
        historicalElement.get(attribute.getValue()).add(attribute);
    } else {
        historicalElement.put(attribute.getValue(), 
             new ArrayList<Attribute>(Arrays.asList(attribute)));     
    }
}
```

If you're using Java 8, you can directly use [`Map#merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method to avoid that extra testing:

```
if(attribute.getDate().compareTo(currentDate) < 0) {
    historicalElement.merge(
                attribute.getValue(), 
                new ArrayList<Attribute>(Arrays.asList(attribute)), 
                ArrayList::addAll);
}
```

You can also use Stream API and lambda here:

```
List<Attribute> currentElement = attributes.stream()
      .filter(a -> a.getDate().compareTo(currentDate) == 0)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
Map<Integer, List<Attribute>> historicalElement = attributes.stream()
      .filter(a -> a.getDate().compareTo(currentDate) < 0)
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Attribute::getValue));
```

Answer (score -1):

Aren’t you trying to put a **single** `Attribute` in a `Map` where it requires a `List` of Attributes, here:

```
//iterating the entire list
for(final Attribute attribute : attributes) 
{
  if(attribute.getDate() == currentDate)
  {
      currentElement.add(attribute);
  }
  if(attribute.getDate() < currentDate)
  {
      historicalElement.put(attribute.getValue(), attribute)  // HERE   
  }
}
```

If you want it to be single attribute, this should change:

**From:** `Map<Integer, List<Attribute>> historicalElement = new HashMap<Integer, List<Attribute>>();`

**To:** `Map<Integer, List<Attribute>> historicalElement = new HashMap<Integer, Attribute>()`;